# How to iterate a dataframe in every second or third id with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, with id, username, and date. I sorted the data frame by id. How to make new data frames, that contains **every second or third id?**
In my task **the user names and the rows here are not relevant**, **just the id's**.
I need to get every second or third id in the same dataframe.
If you see an ID in multiple times I need to count this as 1.
My example is correct please check it.

Here is my code where I made a Data Frame and I sorted it by id:

```
import pandas as pd

id = ['11', '11', '11', '15', '15', '15', '23', '23', '25']
username = ['usera','userb','userc','userd','usere','userf','userd','usere','userf']
date = ['2021-05-04','2021-05-05','2021-05-05','2021-05-06','2021-06-07','2021-06-08','2021-07-09','2021-03-09','2021-04-10']

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'username': username, 'date': date})


dx = df.sort_values(by=['id'], ignore_index=True) #Sort because the dataframe not sorted. by default
print(dx) 

Here is some expected output:

  #dx = get every second value
   id username        date
0  11    usera  2021-05-04
1  11    userb  2021-05-05
2  11    userc  2021-05-05

6  23    userd  2021-07-09
7  23    usere  2021-03-09
....



# Get every third by id:

  id username        date
0  11    usera  2021-05-04
1  11    userb  2021-05-05
2  11    userc  2021-05-05
8  25    userf  2021-04-10
.....
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

- Use [np.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to get the sorted unique ids
- slice the array for every 2nd/3rd ids
- use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to slice the dataframe

Code:

```
unique_ids = np.unique(df['id'])

# every 2nd
every_2nd = df[df['id'].isin(unique_ids[::2])

# every third
every_3rd = df[df['id'].isin(unique_ids[::3])
```

Comment: Ok, yeah, that's a bit more straight-forward than my solution, assuming `df` is always sorted by `'id'`. Nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```py
# kick out non-unique IDs
ids = sorted(list(set(df.id.values.tolist())))

# get every 2nd ID (or 3rd, respectively)
ids_new = [i for i in ids[::2]]

# filter the dataframe accordingly
df_new = df[df.id.isin(ids_new)]
```